# How different sizes of water bubbles behaves in space

Tags: everyday-life, space

I watched a YouTube video of Chris Hadfield talking about different preventive measure for spills in space station. He is using water to demonstrate spills in space station. At [0.24sec](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Hj3GnPRsJ4#t=24) the initially formed smaller water bubbles accelerates fast and moves away in different direction from the tube whereas bigger water bubbles accelerate slowly. is there any scientific reason for this behavior?

Comment: All about the Surface-to-Volume ratio. Small bubbles have more surface-to-volume and so the surface energy (which is least for a sphere) pulls accreting bubbles into a sphere faster. Larger bubbles have more volume-to-surface, so the force of surface pulling bubble into a sphere doesn't accelerate the bulk as much and it takes longer. Not putting this in full answer because I don't have equations and full explanations to back it up. Another physicist could do much better and more correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason for the water-bubbles are the [hydrogen bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond): They keep the $H$<sub>$2$</sub>$O$ atoms together, forming a mass (a very instable mass though).

So when some outside force is being applied to these bubbles, they behave like any other moving object on earth, having a kinetic energy:

$$F_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Because the smaller water bubbles have a smaller mass $m_s$, they accelerate much faster than the big water bubble with a big mass $m_b$, as soon as they come out of the water bottle:

$$v_{small} = √\frac{2F_k}{m_{s}}> v_{big}= √\frac{2F_k}{m_{b}}$$

Strictly speaking, you'll have to derive these formulas by time in order to get the acceleration $a$ (but that's not inherently necessary to understand the underlying physics):

$$a_{small} = \frac{dv_{small}}{dt} > a_{big} = \frac{dv_{big}}{dt}$$

Clearly, there might some other forces like air vents being responsible for the smaller bubbles to move faster in this or another direction, but the underlying formulas would be the same, just apply any other outside force to the mass and you can calculate their corresponding speed and acceleration.